# Unix error, If-then-statement syntax

Tags: unix, if-statement, syntax

```
if [ $#!=2 ]
then
    echo "Please enter two text files"
fi
```

This gives me:

```
swap.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
'wap.sh: line 12: `fi
```

Comment: Put a space between the values and the operator in your test:  `if [ $# != 2 ]`.

Comment: and i actually wrote it in nano in the shell

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two distinct problems here.

First, the correct syntax for that comparison requires spaces around the `!=` operator:

```
if [ $# != 2 ]
then
    echo "Please enter two text files"
fi
```

But without those spaces, it's not a syntax error, it's merely incorrect.  `$#!=2` should simply expand to a single word, such as `2!=2` -- and the `[` or `test` command, when given a single word, simply tests whether that word is empty or not. So the code you posted *should* always print `"Please enter two text files"`, even if you give it two arguments. Adding the spaces should fix that problem.

The way the error message is formatted (and I had to edit your question to make that show up correctly; backticks in inline code are tricky in Markdown), it appears that your script has Windows-style line endings. If you have a program like `dos2unix`, you can use it to convert your script to Unix-style line endings. But read the man page carefully; unlike most Unix-style text filters, `dos2unix` modifies its input file.

Windows-style line endings consist of a carriage return followed by a line feed, or `\r\n`. Your shell (bash?) recognizes the `\n` as an end-of-line character, but the `\r` is just another character, so rather than seeing `fi` as a token, it sees `if\r`. And when it prints that token in the error message, the `\r` causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the current line, overwriting the file name. The actual error message looks like this:

```
swap.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
'wap.sh: line 12: `fi
```

but it's really this:

```
swap.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
swap.sh: line 12: `fi\r'
```

(Are you on Cygwin? That's where this kind of problem most commonly shows up.)

Comment: I had [ $# != 2] i put that back.
no i did not use that program. i used nano on the shell

Comment: What does `file swap.sh` tell you? What operating system are you using?